# Run Macro if mandatory SHeet name exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro and its dependent on Specific sheet name 'PRODUCTS45' problem is if a user run the macro on different sheet e.g. Sheet1 it throws debug error.
can anyone help me to make macro run only when sheet 'PRODUCTS45' is present and if not throws msgbox that mandatory sheet is not present.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub FlagWord()
        Dim R As Range, WS As Worksheet
        Dim RE As Object
        Dim C As Range, D As Range
        Dim S As String
        Dim I As Long, J As Long

    S = InputBox("Enter desired word")

    'Current filled in range
    Set WS = Worksheets("SHEET")
'case sensitive sheet name and its required to run macro if this is not present macro should not run
    With WS
        Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Set R = R.Resize(columnsize:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
    End With

    If Not S = "" Then

    'If S not present then add column
    With WS.Rows(1)
        Set C = .Find(what:=S, after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    'Add column if not already present
        If C Is Nothing Then
            Set R = R.Resize(columnsize:=R.Columns.Count + 1)
            R(1, R.Columns.Count) = S
        End If

    End If 'no new column if S is blank

    'do the word match
    'Clear the data area
    With R
        .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).ClearContents
    End With

    'fill in the data
    'use regex to allow for easy word boundaries
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Global = False 'only need a single match
        .ignorecase = True
        For Each C In R.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(R.Rows.Count - 1).Cells
            For Each D In R.Rows(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(columnsize:=R.Columns.Count - 1).Cells
            .Pattern = "\b" & D.Text & "\b"
                If .test(C.Text) = True Then
                    R(C.Row, D.Column) = "YES"
                End If
            Next D
        Next C
    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Public Sub CheckForSheetBeforeCallingFlagWord()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bolFound As Boolean

bolFound = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "PRODUCTS45" Then bolFound = True
Next ws
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "Required sheet 'PRODUCTS45' not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

Call flagword

End Sub
```

This procedure checks for the existence of the required sheet. If it is not found then you get a message box and nothing else happens. If the sheet is found then the other procedure gets called (and executed).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reference a worksheet that doesn't exist will throw an error. You can use an error handler to trap this and give the desired message.

```
Sub myMacro()
    On Error GoTo sheetNotFound
    doStuff ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PRODUCTS45")
    Exit Sub
sheetNotFound:
    MsgBox "PRODUCTS45 not found"
End Sub

Sub doStuff(ws As Worksheet)
' remaining code goes here
End Sub
```